# Plotting graph with gnuplot in Shell scripting

Tags: shell

I have to plot a graph using `gnuplot` with the help of shell script.
I have written this code but its not working. I want to plot the graph in a html file so that I can see that graph in browser.

```
 echo "set term canvas mousing size 500, 500
 set output "file_name.html"
 plot 'my_file.txt' with lines" | gnuplot
```

I have saved this file in .bash on the desktop.
Now I wrote this in terminal but it didn't work

```
sh file_name.bash
```

Please someone help me out with this. I am totally stuck with this thing since yesterday. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple errors,

- you use double-quotes within the `echo` which will not work. change it to single-quotes
- use semi-colon instead of a line break for multiple `gnuplot` commands

So resulting script should be something like this

```
echo "set term canvas mousing size 500, 500; set output 'file_name.html'; plot 'my_file.txt' with lines" | gnuplot
```

or

```
cat << __EOF | gnuplot
set term canvas mousing size 500, 500
set output "file_name.html"
plot 'my_file.txt' with lines
__EOF
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use `gnuplot << __EOF`?